# Parsley 2.0 noconflict with $

Tags: parsley.js

I am using the new Parsley version (2.0) and I have a problem with $. I put parsley+remote.js and the console says me:

"$ is not a function".

I have in my jsp the next code:

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

With Parsley 1.x I never had problems. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It should be fixed in new released RC3 version. Best